# Xcode - Adding constraints to UITableView so that it fits all screen sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I've read quite a few tutorials and watched numerous videos on using constraints in Xcode. For some reason, I'm still missing certain aspects that are necessary to make the user interface look the way it's supposed to for all screen sizes.

Currently, I have a UITableView laying on a view controller. The view controller is set to "Inferred" size and I have all of the different sized devices open in Assistant Editor Preview to the right so I can view the changes. I've encountered multiple problems attempting to get the constraints correct for the different screen sizes.

Problem 1: The UITableView has a width set to 600. This causes dead space to the right of the table view on the iPad preview and it causes the UITableView to extend too far on the smaller devices. If I make the width of the table view smaller so that it fits within the preview of all screen sizes and then pin the left and right edges of the table view to the edge of the Superview by specifying 0 and unchecking constrain to margins, the result I'm seeing in preview is that the entire table view disappears completely from each device size. I was surprised by this because I thought by pinning the table view to the margins, it would make the table view fit within each of the screens.

Problem 2: (This is a completely different scenario from Problem 1, above.) In this situation, I've left the size of the table view to 600 and just specified constraints for the internal components of the cell contained within the tableview. In this case, the table view is still slightly not wide enough for the iPad dimensions and it extends too far on the smaller devices which makes components in the cells to be truncated and off of center.

I've primarily been working in Storyboard with Any width, Any height set. However, if I change the setting to Compact width, Any height, I can alter the constraints to fit the smaller devices a little better, but there's still a problem with getting things to work between the 5.5 inch screen and the smaller devices.

I would like to get my UITableView to extend all the way to the edges on each device and I would like to have the view inside of the cell remain centered and keep it's relative size on each of the devices. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using a tablviewcontroller or a uitableview in a regular viewcontroller.

Comment: I'm using a UITableView in a regular view controller.

Comment: That is quite odd, because what Andre said should work. So you just dragged a uitableview out of the library and dropped it in the VC?  You should then be able to size it to anything you want if it hasn't snapped into frame. Then set constraints.  Have you tried with a new VC?

Comment: Andre's suggestion did work. The results in the Assistant Editor Preview weren't accurate in comparison to what was actually shown on the simulator. There was also a constraint that was missing which caused the layout to be displayed improperly at runtime. It's working now, though. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to make your tableview to "fill" the whole screen (device-independent) the only thing you have to do is to pin its 4 edges (top, left, bottom, right) to its superview (the viewcontrollers view in your case) with a constant of 0.
you do not specify a specific width (like in your case 600) or height.

good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Andre. I've tried that, but for some reason, my components still extend beyond the smaller screen sizes. I haven't specified the width of the table view as a constraint. I just see where the default width is set to 600.

Comment: you're welcome! could you maybe host your project somehow so i can take a look?

Comment: Use Leading space and Trailing space